# Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(undefined,undefi…"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm goint to make a bubble chart using d3.v3.js following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0PpaI0UlkE&t=621s) tutorial:

The chart is drawn fine when the json data is loaded from `mydata.json` file but I get error when loading the very same json from a url:

```
var JSON_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
 //This works fine:
//var JSON_URL = "/assets/mydata.json";  

var width = 800, 
    height = 600;

var canvas = d3.select("#bubble").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(50,50)");

var pack = d3.layout.pack()
    .size(width, height-50)
    .padding(10)

d3.json(JSON_URL, function(data) {

    console.log('server data is:', data);
    //server data is: {"name":"animal","children":[{"name":"cat","value":4},{"name":"dog","value":5},{"name":"fish","value":10}]}

    var nodes = pack.nodes(data);
    var node = canvas.selectAll(".node")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + ","+ d.y + ")" ;});

    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) {return d.r; })
        .attr("fill", "steelblue")
        .attr("opacity", 0.25)
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue" )
        .attr("stroke-width", "2");

    node.append("text")
        .text(function(d) {return d.children ? "" : d.name ;})


})
```

The json data in `/assets/mydata.json`:

```
{    
    "name" : "animals",
    "children" : [
        {"name":"dog", "value": 5},
        {"name":"cat", "value": 4},
        {"name":"fish", "value": 10}
    ]
}
```

The error that I get:

```
Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(undefined,undefi…".
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(undefined,undefined)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32327489/error-invalid-value-for-g-attribute-transform-translateundefined-undefined)

Comment: I have no clue. I guess they are `d3` internal conventions to deal with json. I just followed the tutorial linked above.

Comment: let me check the link

Comment: @Ivan I saw that question but did not help me.

Comment: Can you show what comes out when logging `nodes` just after the line `var nodes = pack.nodes(data);`?

Comment: sure: `nodes ["{"name":"animals","children":[{"name":"dog","value…me":"cat","value":4},{"name":"fish","value":10}]}"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because `d.x` and `d.y` are `undefined`. That means you are not importing the D3 template correctly.

Just before you import the JSON file you need to import the layout from the D3 library:

```
var pack = d3.layout.pack()
    .size([width, height - 50]) // <- size
```

Notice that the `size` method takes in an array as the first parameter: `[width, height]`:

> **`force.size([width, height])`**
>
> **If size is specified**, sets the available layout size to the specified two-element array of numbers representing x and y. **If size is not specified**, returns the current size, which defaults to `[1, 1]`.
>
> - [D3 Documentation](https://d3-wiki.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/master/Force-Layout/?q=size&check_keywords=yes&area=default)

---

Concerning your problem with the JSON file:

Use the line below just before declaring `nodes`:

```
data = (typeof data == "string") ? JSON.parse(data) : data;
```

to parse the JSON string to a JavaScript object if need be.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I fixed the size but still get the same error when json is loaded from the server. Strangely, the chart is drawn fine when the data  is loaded from local `/assets/mydata.json`

Comment: @Babr, "when JSON is loaded from the server": what URL are you using?

Comment: I load json from `http://127.0.0.1:8080` . I noticed that `nodes` generated is different depending on from where the json is loaded.

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8080` is not a JSON file, you need to specify the path to the JSON file. Where is you JSON file on your server? `http://127.0.0.1:8080/assets/mydata.json`?

Comment: Well, I supposed that d3 simply fetches json from the url. The server api responds with the json at GET / .

Comment: @Babr, No D3 will not go in and find the JSON file for you. You need to specify the *exact* URL path to the JSON file you would like to use. It seems you are using a local server, right? So you have control over the files inside this server. Try to tell me where you have saved this JSON file on your server (find the path to this file).

Comment: The backend api server (running on 8080) responds with the json  at `/` endpoint. The frontend runs on port 3000.

Comment: @Babr, All right, just to be clear if you go ahead on a browser and go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` will you get the JSON displayed on your page?

Comment: Here is what I get in browser  when I visit `http://127.0.0.1:8080`:   `"{\"name\":\"animals\",\"children\":[{\"name\":\"dog\",\"value\":5},{\"name\":\"cat\",\"value\":4},{\"name\":\"fish\",\"value\":10}]}"`

Comment: Ok, that's good, please tell me what comes out of `console.log('server data is:', data);` (for both paths: `/assets/mydata.json` and the localhost one). The result should be different...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174555/discussion-between-babr-and-ivan).